# SQL Server Management Studio 2017 didn't show server name

Tags: .net, sql-server-2017, ssms-2017

I installed SSMS 2017 first then I installed SQL Server 2017. But it doesn't show any server names. Any one knows why its happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your SQL server service is running. If its not running there wont be any instance available/visible.

Comment: where can i check that

Comment: Go on search and type "SQL Server Configuration Manager" it is the one with a red toolbox. Then check if SQL Server is "Running".

Comment: If your problem is resolved remember to accept my answer! Let me know if the problem persist.

Comment: sure definitely